# How to display child component from left to right

Tags: css, angular

I am rendering child component in for loop from parent component. My parent component should be float to right at the bottom of screen then after each render of child component should be render to left to my parent component

Parent component :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="ng-chat-view">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="ng-chat-people" [ngClass]="{'ng-chat-people-collapsed':isCollapsed}">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ng-chat-title shadowed" (click)="onChatTitleClicked($event)">
              <span>
                Farmer List
              </span>
            </a>
            <input *ngIf="!isCollapsed" id="ng-chat-search_friend" type="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="search" (ngModelChange)="getFarmerBySearchVal(search)"
            />
            <ul id="ng-chat-users" *ngIf="!isCollapsed">
              <li *ngFor="let user of farmers">
                <div *ngIf="!user.imageUrl" class="icon-wrapper">
                  <i class="user-icon"></i>
                </div>

                <img *ngIf="user.imageUrl" alt="" class="avatar" height="30" width="30"  src="{{user.imageUrl}}"/>
                <strong title="{{user.user}}" (click)="openChatWindow(user, true)">{{user.name}}</strong>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 m-l">
          <div *ngFor="let user of userInfo; let i = index">
            <div>
              <app-chatwindow [userInfo]="user" (onWindowCloseNotify)="onWindowCloseDeleteUserFromList($event)"></app-chatwindow>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have attached screenshot of desired output :
Parent component should be:
[image]

Child component should be:
[image]

Current output:
[image: Current output]

Comment: Could you provide the code.

Comment: @TheHeadRush source code updated

Comment: @LXhelili currently its working fine but that should be render from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example.
Parent should be floated to the right, as well as the childrens.

```css
.chat {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.chat li {
  width: 160px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  float: right; 
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="chat">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But the problem is that col-md-12 is expanding to full screen hence the scroll of background element is not working if you try to scroll on horizontal space of chat user list component